# Replace a string from mySQL Table

Tags: mysql

Hi I am using following code to replace '[' only in all instances where it occurs right after a backslash '\':

```
UPDATE articles SET notes = REPLACE (notes, '\[', '\(')
```

However, '[' is replaced everywhere even when '\' and '[' don't appear together. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to escape the backslash `\\` so use `\\[`